# Do I have to specify the package version when reporting a bug with ubuntu-bug?

Tags: bug-reporting, apport

Reporting a bug from Ubuntu using the `ubuntu-bug [package]` command adds a couple of attached files to the bug, that include relevant information about a bug and that package.

However, when filling the form describing the bug there's a note requiring the package version and a command to find it out.
Is it truly necessary or the ubuntu-bug command handles that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *ubuntu-bug* automatically adds it.

Take for example [bug #819150](https://launchpad.net/bugs/819150) (a random bug). It has been created using *ubuntu-bug* and contains the following information:

```
ProblemType: Crash
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 11.10
Package: indicator-appmenu 0.2.91-0ubuntu2
```

---

The text that tells you to include the Ubuntu/package version in your report is the same text that is shown when you report bugs without using *ubuntu-bug*, that's why you are seeing it.

In fact, at the end of the list of what you need to provide, there's written:

> Most of this information is gathered when you use apport to report the bug. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for complete details.

Given that *ubuntu-bug* is part of Apport, that sentence means: “if you are using *ubuntu-bug*, you do not have to provide that stuff yourself”.